# EXE version numbers -- how to correctly compare minor versions

Tags: windows, version, exe

Windows EXE files have version numbers attached to them, consisting of four digits separated by dots (e.g. 1.0.0.0).

**Question**: What is the correct way to compare these numbers? In particular, is 1.15.0.0 > 1.2.0.0 (since 15 > 2) or vice versa (since, mathematically, 1.15 < 1.2)?

---

*Background: One of my applications has reached 3.9.* and I would like to know wheter I can continue with 3.10.* without installers or other components that compare version numbers causing trouble.*

Comment: Since the components are separated I'd treat them as separate numbers, i.e. 15 > 2, but I guess it depends on the conventions of whoever wrote the app.

Comment: @Rup: Since the EXE file format is standardized and these version numbers can be read via Windows API, I guess that their semantics is standardized as well.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way is to consider each component (delimited by periods '.') in turn as a **numeric** rather than **string** value. So, yes 1.15.0.0 is > 1.2.0.0

If you use Powershell it has a built-in version object (based on .NET's [`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) type):  `[version]` that will perform this functionality for you.

[For reference, the individual components are `Major.Minor.Build.Revision`]

Answer (score 1):

As stated in MSDN [at this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The *version* consists of two 32-bit integers, defined by four 16-bit
>   integers.

This mean, given two versions in format "Major.Minor.Release.Build", you can be confident you'll always end up having enough data to assemble them into 64-bit unsigned integer values like this:

```
int64_t i1 = (v1->Major << 48) | (v1->Minor << 32) | (v1->Release << 16) | v1->Build;
int64_t i2 = (v2->Major << 48) | (v2->Minor << 32) | (v2->Release << 16) | v2->Build;
```

So you can now just compare two 64 bit values like:

```
if (i1 > i2) { ... }
```

Sorry for solving it after 5 years, but I was walking around...